# Headcount in opencv

Tags: opencv

i am new to opencv. i have to implement a headcount. 
my idea is:

1. Identification of circular objects

   - We will start by edge detection to find border line of each shape.
     sort through the image matrix pixel by pixel
     for each pixel, analyze each of the 8 pixels surrounding it
     record the value of the darkest pixel, and the lightest pixel
     if (darkest_pixel_value - lightest_pixel_value) > threshold) 
     then rewrite that pixel as 1; 
     else rewrite that pixel as 0;
   - Now we detect shapes
     count the number of continuous edges
     a sharp change in line direction signifies a different line 
     do this by determining the average vector between adjacent pixels
     if one line, then its a circle
     by measure angles between lines more information can be deduced (rhomboid, equilateral   triangle, etc.)
2. Face detection

   - This part includes two common approaches based on features and color. The basic idea of the algorithm is to find objects resembling an eye, then on the basis of geometric face characteristics try to join two the objects into an eye pair.
     Steps:

     1. Unimportant colors are eliminated from the image and insignificant colors are replaced with white color.
     2. The image is then converted to grayscale.
     3. The image is filtered with a median filter (unimportant white regions are blurred)
     4. White regions are segmented using a Region growth algorithm.
     5. Hough transform is applied to find circles
     6. For each region the best possible circle is found
     7. Using geometric face characteristics the pair of eyes is found

is this the right way to proceed or is there an easier way?
i want to count the number (estimate) of people found in a crowd (meetings, gatherings)
can you help me with the codes please?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use the OpenCV built-in face detection.See http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/FaceDetection for detailed instructions.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar project.

You need to get the best image so concentrate on fixing saturation, contrast and intensity.

If your planning to use color, if you want skin color detection for example, than you need to fix white balance.

Don't think of headcount, instead think of people count.

You need a good background segmentation, use Gaussian Mixture of Models 
combined with other background modeling algorithm.

If this is an outdoor application you need shadow detection.

Get foreground blobs and then determine where people are in those blobs.

If your counting heads, you need to detect *omega* shape for the head and shoulders.

You will need tracking for occlusions and people crossing.

You can also use human body classification, opencv has haarcascade_fullbody.xml

These are just some ideas...